# Verilog test bench compiles but simulate stops at 700 ticks

Tags: verilog, boolean-logic

First off please forgive any spelling mistakes, English is not my first language.

For a project I'm trying to simulate some "basic" logic using iverilog. Currently I have a simulation that for some reason hangs on the third downward flank of the clock signal. The test bench compiles fine however during simulation it stops at 6ns. Investigation of the signals shows no undefined signals or latch situations as far as I can see. The only signal that changes as at that time is the CLK signal.

The simulation is a simple 2-bit up counter with asynchronous clear and reset (CBU22) and the goal is to have the counter increase until it reaches up to its maximum value and than hold this signal until it is reset. So when CBU22.Q0 and CBU22.Q1 are both high, this will cause CBU22.CAO to be become high which in turn should pull CBU22.EN_IN low preventing it from counting further.

If someone knows why the simulation hangs I would very much appreciate your input.

The commands I use to compile and run the code are:

```
> iverilog -o test -ylibrary test_tb.v
> ./test
```

I'm certain this is correct because I use the same command on other models and these simulate just fine.

This is the code for the test problematic bench

**test_tb.v:**

```
`include "library/lsc_minimal.v"
`timescale 1 ns / 1 ns

// Define Module for Test Fixture
module test_tb();

// Inputs
    reg CLK;
    reg CD;
    reg EN;

// Outputs
    wire Q0;
    wire Q1;

// Bidirs


// Instantiate the UUT
    test UUT (
            .EN(EN),
            .CLK(CLK),
            .CD(CD),
            .Q0(Q0),
            .Q1(Q1)
            );

    always #1 CLK <= !CLK;

// Initialize Inputs
// You can add your stimulus here
    initial begin
    $dumpfile ("signals.vcd"); 
    $dumpvars;
        // initialize variables
        CLK = 0;
        CD = 0;
        EN = 0;

        //Simulation parameters
        #1 EN <= 1;
        #8 $finish;
    end

endmodule //test_tb
```

This is the verilog model I'm trying to simulate

**library/test.v:**

```
/* Verilog model */

module test(EN, CLK, CD, Q0, Q1);
    input EN, CLK, CD;
    output Q0, Q1;
    wire CAI, CAO, EN_IN, NOT_CAO;

buf (CAI,1);
and (EN_IN,EN,NOT_CAO);
not (NOT_CAO,CAO);

CBU22 I1 (
            .Q0(Q0),
            .Q1(Q1),
            .CAO(CAO),
            .CAI(CAI),
            .CLK(CLK),
            .EN(EN_IN),
            .CD(CD)
            );

endmodule //
```

Changing the and gate in the test module allows the simulation to complete however that is not the behaviour I want to simulate.

Finally this is the library I'm including. It is based on a library provided by Lattice. The final code will be implemented on one of their devices. I find it very unlikely there is a problem is this library however I have included it so you can use it to reproduce my problem.

**library/lsc_minimal.v:**

```
/*
Minimal modules for counter test
Variables changed to remove duplicate names
*/

/*
* "Cell CBU22"                                                                 *
*/

`timescale 10 ps / 10 ps 
module CBU22(
    Q0, Q1, CAO, CAI, 
    CLK, EN, CD);

    output Q0;
    output Q1;
    output CAO;
    input CAI;
    input CLK;
    input EN;
    input CD;

    FD21 I1  (.Q0(QI0), .D0(CBU22_I8_Z0 ), .CLK(CLK), .CD(CD));
    FD21 I2  (.Q0(QI1), .D0(CBU22_I9_Z0 ), .CLK(CLK), .CD(CD));
    AND2 I3  (.Z0(CBU22_I3_Z0 ), .A0(CAI), .A1(EN));
    AND3 I4  (.Z0(CBU22_I4_Z0 ), .A0(QI0), .A1(CAI), .A2(EN));
    AND4 I5  (.Z0(CAO), .A0(QI0), .A1(QI1), .A2(CAI), .A3(EN));
    BUF I6  (.Z0(Q1), .A0(QI1));
    BUF I7  (.Z0(Q0), .A0(QI0));
    LXOR2 I8  (.Z0(CBU22_I8_Z0 ), .A0(QI0), .A1(CBU22_I3_Z0 ));
    LXOR2 I9  (.Z0(CBU22_I9_Z0 ), .A0(QI1), .A1(CBU22_I4_Z0 ));
endmodule

/*
* "Cell AND2"                                                                 *
*/

`timescale 10 ps / 10 ps 

module AND2 (Z0, A0, A1);

    input  A0;
    input  A1;

    output  Z0;

    and I10 (Z0, A0, A1);

endmodule

/*
* "Cell AND3"                                                                 *
*/
`timescale 10 ps / 10 ps
module AND3 (Z0, A0, A1, A2);

    input  A0;
    input  A1;
    input  A2;

    output  Z0;

    and I11 (Z0, A0, A1, A2);

endmodule

/*
* "Cell AND4"                                                                 *
*/

`timescale 10 ps / 10 ps
module AND4 (Z0, A0, A1, A2, A3);

    input  A0;
    input  A1;
    input  A2;
    input  A3;

    output  Z0;

    and I12 (Z0, A0, A1, A2, A3);

endmodule

/*
* "Cell BUF"                                                                  *
*/
`timescale 10 ps / 10 ps
module BUF (Z0, A0);

    input  A0;

    output  Z0;

    buf I13  (Z0, A0);

endmodule

/*
* "Cell LXOR2"                                                                *
*/
`timescale 10 ps / 10 ps
module LXOR2 (Z0, A0, A1);

    input  A0;
    input  A1;

    output  Z0;

    xor I14 (Z0, A0, A1);

endmodule

/**************
*     FD21    *
***************/

`timescale 10 ps / 10 ps
module FD21 (Q0, D0, CLK, CD);

  input   CLK, D0, CD;
  output  Q0;
  supply1 reset;
  //reg Q0;

  not  blk0 (t1, reset);
  or   blk1 (t2, t1, CD);

  DFF_FD blk2 (Q0, D0, CLK, t2);

endmodule

/**************************
*     PRIMITIVE DFF_FD    *
**************************/

`timescale 10 ps / 10 ps
primitive DFF_FD (Q, D, CP, R);

    output Q;  
    input  D, CP, R;
    reg    Q; 

    initial Q = 0; //Added to prevent from remaining undefined

    table
    //  D   CP      R   :   Qt  :   Qt+1

        1   (01)    0   :   ?   :   1;  // clocked data
        0   (01)    0   :   ?   :   0;

        0   (01)    x   :   ?   :   0;  // pessimism
        0    ?      x   :   0   :   0;  // pessimism

        1    0      x   :   0   :   0;  // pessimism
        1    x    (?x)  :   0   :   0;  // pessimism
        1    1    (?x)  :   0   :   0;  // pessimism

        x    0      x   :   0   :   0;  // pessimism
        x    x    (?x)  :   0   :   0;  // pessimism
        x    1    (?x)  :   0   :   0;  // pessimism

        1   (x1)    0   :   1   :   1;  // reducing pessimism
        0   (x1)    0   :   0   :   0;                          
        1   (0x)    0   :   1   :   1;  
        0   (0x)    0   :   0   :   0;  


        ?   ?       1   :   ?   :   0;  // asynchronous clear

        ?   (?0)    ?   :   ?   :   -;  // ignore falling clock
        ?   (1x)    ?   :   ?   :   -;  // ignore falling clock
        *    ?      ?   :   ?   :   -;  // ignore the edges on data

        ?    ?    (?0)  :   ?   :   -;  // ignore the edges on clear 

    endtable
endprimitive
```

I tried to be as clear as possible however if something is unclear please let me know.

Comment: You are brutally mixing blocking and non-blocking delayed assignments in your testbench, so probably it is not doing what you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you for your response Eugine,however the mixing is intentional. The blocking assignments are used to initialize the test bench. Changing everything to non blocking (or blocking statements) makes no difference. I'm beginning to suspect the problem is in the FD21 module which is defined using a table in the primitive DFF_FD in **lsc_minimal.v**. However I can't quite figure out what in the table causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never quite figured out what was wrong with the original circuit (don't have the time) but replacing test.v with the description below allowed the simulation to finish and produce correct results.

```
/* Verilog model */

module test(EN, CLK, CD, Q0, Q1);
    input EN, CLK, CD;
    output Q0, Q1;
    wire CAI, CAO, EN_IN, NOT_CAO;

buf (CAI,1);
and (W_1,Q0,Q1);
not (EN_IN,W_1);

CBU22 I1 (
            .Q0(Q0),
            .Q1(Q1),
            .CAO(CAO),
            .CAI(CAI_IN),
            .CLK(CLK),
            .EN(EN_IN),
            .CD(CD)
            );

endmodule //
```